# How can I make fake records in a way that some of them have specific values in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I need to make some fake records in laravel testing in a way that some of them have specific values.

for example I need to create 20 fake records of countries name and want to name the two records "USA" and "UK" and other values  is not important.

If I use this code all records name will be same:

```
$country = Country::factory()->count(20)->create(['name'=> 'USA']);
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this in one single command. You'll need to call this twice with `count(1)` for US and UK. Then do a loop from 1 to 18 with a random string.

Comment: No idea if Laravel supports this, but maybe you could define the value part of the array as a closure that returns a random value? `->create(['name' => function() { return ['USA', 'UK'][random_int(0, 1)]; })`

Comment: You can take advantage of [`Sequences`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#sequences) but even that will not fully solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```php
$country = Country::factory()
    ->count(20)
    ->sequence(new Sequence(
        function($sequence) { 
            return $index === 0 ? 
            ['name' => 'UK'] : 
                $index === 1 ? 
                ['name' => 'USA'] : 
                ['name' => $this->faker->word()]; 
        }
    ))
    ->create();
```

That way, if the sequence is in its first iteration, name will be set to 'UK', second iteration will be 'USA', and after that a random word.

Answer (score 0):

Why just use 2 lines?

```
Country::factory()->count(10)->create(['name'=> 'USA']);
Country::factory()->count(10)->create();
```

Or you can put into your factory like:

```
/**
 * Define the model's default state.
 *
 * @return array<string, mixed>
 */
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->boolean ? $this->faker->randomElement(['USA', 'UK']) : null,
```